# callback not getting called when adding arguments

Tags: javascript, events, callback, cordova

I have a javascript callback that isn't being called when there are arguments passed. This is working in jsbin, so is there any reason why it won't work in phonegap. This should be realy simple.

```
<input type="file" id="soundInput">
<script type="text/javascript">
var type = 0;
function addSoundToSoundMenu() {
    alert("callback success.");
}
var soundInput = document.getElementById('soundInput');
soundInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    handleFileSelect(e, type,addSoundToSoundMenu);
}, false); 

function handleFileSelect(event, type, cb) {
    var file = this.files[0]; // FileList object
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
        gotFS(fs,file,type);
    }, fail);
}
</script>
```

The above example does not call handleFileSelect(). it only works when handleFileSelect is passed without any arguments.

```
soundInput.addEventListener('change',handleFileSelect,false);
```

and ofcourse I remove the args to handleFileSelect() to get it to work.

Is there something I am missing. Does creating the input field programmatically change how the event dispatcher is handled.

Is there anything else I can try, maybe something with closure? Has anyone had problems with this before? I can't imagine it has anything to do with phoneGap.

Comment: Where are `type` and `addSoundToSoundMenu` defined? And it sure looks like your arguments you're passing don't line up with the parameters defined for `handleFileSelect`. What console errors are you getting? Reference Errors?

Comment: Sorry I've played with this a lot, They line up. I'll fix it in question.

Comment: I finally figured it out, it is the "this.files[0];" in the handleFileSelect function. If it is not the direct return variable of event This doesn't point at anything useful, my oh my. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: I can't answer my own question so anyone feel free :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the event object to `handleFileSelect` function. Please do that and see.

```
soundInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    handleFileSelect(e, type,addSoundToSoundMenu);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I found the problem, just to close the question the problem is with

```
var file = this.files[0]; // FileList object
```

in the handleFileSelect function. If handlFileSelect is not the direct callback of the event, "this" doesn't hold a files object.

Oh the joys of programming without a debugger...

Curse you Weinre!